# Using SQL to get values from another table given a table with two columns of key

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, join

After some joins, I've managed to get a table that looks like:

```
src | destination
1   | 2
3   | 4
```

Both source and destinations are IDs and there's another table that is

```
id | name
1  | hello
2  | foo
3  | bar
4  | baz
```

How do I get something like

```
src   | dest
hello | foo
bar   | baz
```

fairly quickly in sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you first table is called `Mapping` and you source/destination names table is called `Locales`.

This is what you want to do:

```
select l1.name as src, l2.name as dest
from Mapping m 
inner join Locales l1 on m.src = l1.id
inner join Locales l2 on m.destination = l2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd use 2 joins to the same table:

```
select a1.name, a2.name
from names a1
   join xref x
      ON x.src = a1.id
   join names a2
      ON x.destination = a2.id
```